# PowerShell: get all child items recursively - without bin/obj folders

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to get a list of all child items of a number of source folders I want to export (=copy) afterwards. However, I do not want to get the bin/obj folders and their sub contents.

My approach so far:

```
Get-ChildItem $RootDirectory -Attributes Directory -Include $includeFilder |
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -exclude 'bin' |% { Write-Host $_.FullName }
```

However, it does not work. The problem seems to be that `-exclude 'bin'` does not match as the whole folder name down the road (something like `C:\Blubb\bin`) is matched.

How to match only the folder name and not the whole path in the `-exclude` statement? Is there maybe an even better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Using @Joey's example, you can re-arrange that a little to avoid searching the bin/obj folders:

```
gci $rootdirectory -Directory -Recurse |
   where { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\(bin|obj)(\\|$)' } |
   gci -File -inc $includeFilter | select FullName
```

Just move the -Recurse and where-object filter up to the first GCI, then GCI on each of the returned directories.

Comment: I'm not sure where in the hierarchy `bin` and `obj` appear, that's why I wrote it that way.

Comment: if he wants to exclude those folders and any sub-content, I don't think it should matter.  If it bin or obj appear anywhere in the directory path, you'd want to exclude that directory.

Comment: Well, if `bin|obj` are only on the top level, this is an elegant way of removing them. If they are picked up by the second `gci`, then it won't suffice.

Comment: Okay.  I made an adjustment (added -File to the second GCI).  That should return only the files from folders that don't have bin or obj anwhere in their path.

Comment: Ouch, stupid me. I didn't notice the `-Recurse` on the first `gci`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a little more explicit. Not terribly nice, but should get the job done:

```
gci $rootdirectory -Directory -inc $includeFilder |
   gci -rec |
   where { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\(bin|obj)(\\|$)' }
   select FullName
```

You could perhaps even drop the second Get-ChildItem.

Comment: Hmm, I hoped there is a faster way, which does not iterate through all files within the bin/obj folders.

Comment: @D.R.: It depends a bit on where in the hierarchy the `bin` and `obj` folders appear.

Answer (score 0):

Reusable filter command:

```
filter Get-Descendents($Filter={1}) { $_ | where $Filter | foreach { $_; if ($_.PSIsContainer) { $_ | Get-ChildItem | Get-Descendents $Filter } } }
```

---

Example:

```
dir C:\code | Get-Descendents { -not $_.PSIsContainer -or $_.Name -notin 'bin', 'obj'}
```

This won't enter a directory that fails the filter.

---

It also allows you to predefine your filters and pass them as parameters.

Example:

```
$myDevItemFilter1 = { -not $_.PSIsContainer -or $_.Name -notin 'bin', 'obj'}
$myDevItemFilter2 = { -not $_.PSIsContainer -or $_.Name -notin '.svn', '.git'}

dir C:\code | Get-Descendents $myDevItemFilter1
dir C:\code | Get-Descendents $myDevItemFilter2
```